# How to get data from Sharepoint excel datasource to Power BI desktop?

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, powerbi

I want to load an excel which is in Share point to Power Bi Desktop.
I have tried loading the sheet by using the data source **SharePoint List** but failed as its throwing an error. Please help me by suggesting any other way.
Thank you.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting. have you seen this https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-data-sources/ link for how to connect?

Comment: Content not found.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Get Data / Web.  It will automatically recognize that the target is an Excel file and generate the M functions to interpret it.

The trick can be getting the true link to the SharePoint file - something you can just paste into a browser's address bar so it will download the file directly.

For SharePoint Online, I use Get a Link / Restricted Link, then delete any trailing query parameters after the file name, typically ?d=blabla

That should also work for SharePoint 2016.  From memory it was easier in the earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest choosing *Sharepoint Folder* from the *Get Data* menu.

Then you need to enter the site's (or subsite) root url (not the direct link to the excel file)

For example, you would connect to.

```
https://yourcompany.sharepoint.com/training/
```

Instead of the full address.

```
https://yourcompany.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/training/_layouts/19/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%2asdfasdfasdfasdf%7D&action=default&uid=%7asdfasdfasdf-4662-A7A5-asdfasdf%7D&ListItemId=2&ListId=%7asdfasdfasdfa3443445&env=prod
```

Then press *Edit* to reveal all of the documents stored at that root. By clicking the *binary* link, the query editor will reveal the contents of the file. Then select the tab you're interested in loading by selecting the *Table* under the *data* column.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to get the data from sharepoint to Power BI:

1. Select the File available to share pont
2. Click on three dots
3. Go to Open-> Open in app
4. In app, click on File -> Info -> Copy Path
5. Open Power BI, New Source-> Web
6. Add URL, delete (data with and after ?)